# Creating multiple folders and subfolder in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, nested, subdirectory

I need to create a folder and subfolder with name from E1 to E10 and inside each folder have 10 more folders, how do i do that in PowerShell ISE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following creates subfolders `E1` through `E10`, and, inside each, subfolders `F1` through `F10`:

```sh
# Creates subdirectories and returns info objects about them.
# -Force means that no error is reported for preexisting subdirs.
# Use $null = New-Item ... to suppress output.
New-Item -Type Directory -Force `
         -Path (1..10 -replace '^', 'E').ForEach({ 1..10 -replace '^', "$_\F" })
```

Note:

- [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) `'^', '...'` is a simple way to *prepend* text to each input array element (each of the sequence numbers created with the `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-), in this case).
- `-replace '$', '...'` would *append*.
- To insert the input in an arbitrary position, use `^.*` to match the entire input and `$&` to refer to it in the replacemenent text; e.g. 
  `-replace '^.*', 'Before-$&-After'`